# Modifying Index Location is Disabled by a Policy

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, search-indexing

I have indexing setup on Windows 10 (build 18363.693) to include 4 different drives, and the index itself is stored on a separate drive.

[image]

I am attempting to set up the index to no longer be on this drive, and move to a different drive, however, I am running into one major roadblock. In the control panel, when I attempt to change the location of the index, I get the following error message:

[image]

I am on a personal machine, that should not have any group policy changed from default (as the machine is *not* domain bound), and I have not made any recent changes that should have enacted this policy to take effect.

What I find odd is that in the [Windows Registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC6TB.jpg), the path to my current index shows as `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SearchNew\Data`, even though the index is currently being stored on drive `G:\`. Along with this, in control panel, the current location of the index is not shown:

[image]

---

**What I have tried so far:**

- Resetting all policies in `gpedit.msc` back to default - meaning 'Not configured' and running `gpupdate`
- My user account **should** be admin, but just in-case I opened control panel from an administrative shell - still no luck

---

I would appreciate any guidance, as the search index appears to no longer be functioning correctly, and as such, I cannot search windows in any way shape or form.

Comment: Use `regedit` to position to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search`. If you see an item named `PreventModifyingIndexedLocations` whose value is `1`, then delete it. Check also `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search`.

Comment: @harrymc No such value exists in my registry.

Comment: Try: (1) [disable Indexing](https://windowsreport.com/indexing-windows-8/), in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search`, set `DataDirectory` to your folder, reboot, enable indexing, reboot. (2) Use [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) to quickly search the registry for the string naming the actual folder of the index, modify all occurences you can find and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc Could you make that into an answer? It fixed the original problem

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure for moving the Windows search index is:

- [Disable Indexing in Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/indexing-windows-8/)
- Use `regedit` to navigate to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search`
- Set the item named `DataDirectory` to the new folder
- Reboot
- Enable indexing
- Reboot

This should work. If it does not, then changes in Windows have moved the location
somewhere else in the registry.
Use the free
[RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html)
to quickly search the entire registry for the string holding the actual folder
of the index, modify all occurrences you can find, and reboot.